# Rails whenever gem: each month on the 20th

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I searched all over the internet for this, and the documentation isn't really talking about monthly jobs in specific. So I was hoping that someone here could tell me how to do this.

I've installed the whenever gem and all I need to know is the right syntax for this:

```
every :month, :on => '20th', :at => '02:00' do
  runner "Mailer.send_friend_sheet"
end
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction..

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever doesn't support an `:on` option as far as I am aware, but you should be able to do

```
every '0 2 20 * *' do
  runner "Mailer.send_friend_sheet"
end
```

The '0 2 20 * *' is simply the relevant cron syntax - see http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/

Comment: Too bad there isn't a readable solution, but it'll do. Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

You can use raw cron syntax as well if you cant figure out how to use with ruby syntax.

What you want will look like:

```
every '0 2 20 * *' do
  command "echo 'you can use raw cron syntax too'"
end
```

Here is a quick cheatsheet for how to use cron syntax

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

Shamelessly stolen from: http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

Answer (score 21):

If you want it more readable you can also just parse a date in text.

```
every 1.month, :at => 'January 20th 2:00am' do
  runner "Mailer.send_friend_sheet"
end
```

This will generate `0 2 20 * *` as well.

Answer (score 12):

Even better:

```
every 1.month, at: 'start of the month at 2am' do
  runner "Mailer.send_friend_sheet"
end
```

Comment: Would be nice if I needed the first day of the month, I needed the 20th, nice syntax though.

Comment: every 1.month, at: 'end of the month at 2am' do
  runner "Mailer.send_friend_sheet"
end

Is something like this valid?