# rails:whenever gem:run job every year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, whenever

How can I write cronjob using whenever gem in rails 4.0 for last day of every year or any specific day of every year.

for ex. 31st dec, 11:59 pm of every year or 15th july of every year.

i am trying this,

```
every 1.year do
  rake "namespace:jobname"
end
```

but where to mention day and time?

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `31st dec, 11:59 pm`,try this

```
every 1.year, :at => 'December 31th 11:59pm' do
  rake "namespace:jobname"
end
```

For `15th july`,try this

```
every 1.year, :at => 'July 15th' do
  rake "namespace:jobname"
end
```

**OR**

```
every '0 0 15 7 *' do
  rake "namespace:jobname"
end
```

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453618/rails-whenever-gem-each-month-on-the-20th)**

**Note:** Didn't tested.

Comment: not working, dude. :(, some string parsing error occuring, I believe due to this string December 31th 11:59pm.